# Cannot send mail from inside a function

Tags: python

```
def send_mail():      
    recv = os.environ.get('mail_username')
    sender = 'alerts@.com'
    receivers = [recv]

    message = f"""From: QA-Security Gate Alerts <alerts@.com>
    To: To Person {recv}
    Subject: Azure function down

    Check Logs
    """

    try:
        smt_obj = smtplib.SMTP('mailrelay.site.com')
        smt_obj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
        print("Successfully sent email")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Sending mail Failed')
        raise  e
```

`send_mail()`

This code works fine when I run it without the function, however, once I put it in the function it runs and prints `"Successfully sent email"` but doesn't actually do so. I have tried adding a `return`  then assigning the function to a variable but still doesn't work.

```
return smt_obj( Inside the function)
# Outside the function
mail = send_mail()
mail.quit()
```

Comment: There's no reason why the same code should work differently when moved into a function. There must have been another difference to before you created the function.

Comment: I think the same, but it really does not send the mail. No exceptions as well..so not sure what's going on.

Comment: is the `sender` address valid?

Comment: @bn_ln Everything is the same. Works instantly if you move it out of the function.

Comment: maybe one thing to try is a debugging server.  Run `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025` , and in the script change your SMTP host to `smtplib.SMTP(host='localhost', port=1025)`.  This works for me regardless of being in a function or not.

Comment: Can you show the two versions of the code? And are you sure that you are not calling a different function that also happens to be named `send_mail()` (if you show the code this should become apparent)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 There is no other function or anything. There is only 1 function, that is all. It might have something to do with the SMTP Object behaviour.

Comment: Can you tap the network interface with tcpdump or wireshark and watch the SMTP conversation?

Comment: @VPfB Client environment, can't do any of that.

Comment: `.sendmail` returns a dict with one entry for each recipient that was refused. However if all recipents were refused, it raises `SMTPRecipientsRefused` and you have only one reciprint ... anyway, just for completness, could you print what is returned in your case?

Comment: @VPfB "Successfully sent email" . That's all. I need to run this inside of an azure function. I am not able to add this code to the exisitng azure function code because it doesn't work inside a function and that is how I need to call it in azure. shows no errors, but sends no mail :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import smtplib
import time
from smtplib import SMTPException

def send_mail(smt_obj, sender, receivers, message):
    try:
        smt_obj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        print("Successfully sent email")
    except SMTPException as e:
        print("Error: unable to send email:", e)
    finally:
        smt_obj.quit()

sender = 'alerts@company.com'
receivers = ['user@company.com']

message = """From: QA-Security Gate Alerts <alerts@company.com>
To: To Person <user@company.com>
Subject: Azure function down

Check Logs
"""

smt_obj = smtplib.SMTP('mailrelay.company.com')
# smt_obj.starttls()

send_mail(smt_obj, sender, receivers, message)
```

Not sure why, but this code works. As I suspected, the behaviour of the SMTP object has probably got to do with this.